# catch href action on <a> using jQuery and class

Tags: jquery, ajax, href

I try to catch the called href using jQuery (based on the class of the link) to be able to use jQuery.load instead.

But the selector don't work on my `<a href>`, if I put the class on a parent `<td>` it works ... any id of what is bad in my jQuery selector (I want to select only some `<a href>` in my table) ?

My html:

```
// Don't work, the page is loaded normally
    <td>
      <a href="mylink" class="urlToMainDiv">
      <a href="mylink2">
    </td>

// Work but on all links
<td class="urlToMainDiv">
  <a href="mylink">
  <a href="mylink2">
</td>
```

My selector:

```
jQuery(".urlToMainDiv a").live("click", function(e){     
   e.preventDefault();  
   // myjQuery load fct
   load_ajax_content(this.href,divId);
```

or

```
jQuery(".urlToMainDiv a").click(function(e){     
  e.preventDefault(); 
  // myjQuery load fct
  load_ajax_content(this.href,divId);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated. You should consider using the new more appropriate [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's doing exactly what you told it to.

`x y` is a **descendant selector** that matches all `y`s inside an `x`.

You want `a.urlToMainDiv`, which will match all `a` elements` which also have that class.

Comment: @ SLaks :Thanks I confused the hierarchical selector

Comment: @ War10ck: I will use `.on()` now

Comment: @Boody: Note that `.on()` takes different parameters.

Comment: @ SLaks: You mean that `jQuery('a.urlToMainDiv').on("click",function(e){` will not work ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select only those links whose `href` is "mylink", then...

...for your first block of html:

```
$('a.urlToMainDiv').click(function () {
```

...and for your second block of html:

```
$('.urlToMainDiv a[href="mylink"]').click(function () {
```